# Orders of numbers modulo another number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $a$ has order $k$, how many of $1, a, a^2, \ldots, a^{k-1}$ have order $k$?

I have no idea where to even begin on this. The only idea I had was saying:

$$\big[a^2\big]^k = \big[a^k\big]^2 = \big[1\big]^2 = \big[1\big]$$
Therefore, $a^2$ also has order $k$.

Repeat for $a^3,\ldots,a^{k-1}$

but I'm sure that that's not even close to being on the right track.

Comment: Correct.${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Euler....IS_ALIVE: Um, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**  The definition of order requires that it be the *minimum* positive exponent producing 1.

For example, if we're working modulo $5$ (say), then $2$ has order $4$, because 
$$2^1=2,\quad 2^2=4,\quad 2^3=3,\quad \fbox{$2^4=1\strut$}$$ but $2^2=4$ has order $2$, because 
$$4^1=4,\quad \fbox{$4^2=1\strut$}$$

Comment: So $a^2$ has order $\frac{k}{2}$, $a^3$ has order $\frac{k}{3}$, etc... implying that none of the other numbers have order $k$?

Comment: @user1359900: Not quite.  For example, $\frac{k}{2}$ or $\frac{k}{3}$ might not be an integer.

Comment: @user1359900: You can see that you've written can't be correct, since much of the time $\frac{k}{c}$ won't be an integer. Also, for an explicit counterexample, note that (again modulo $5$), $2^3=3$ also has order $4$:
$$3^1=3,\quad 3^2=4,\quad 3^3=2,\quad \fbox{$3^4=1\strut$}$$

Comment: So if you can show counter examples like that, how are you supposed to show what the orders of the other numbers are? Is there even a way to tell?

Comment: @user1359900: Note that
$$(a^k)^1,\quad (a^k)^2,\quad (a^k)^3,\quad \ldots$$
is just
$$a^k,\quad a^{2k},\quad a^{3k},\quad \ldots$$
What happens when (for example) $k$ divides $n$? Do you reach $1$ faster? On the other extreme, what happens when $\gcd(k,n)=1$? (It may be helpful to know Fermat's Little Theorem.) Can you then generalize this for any $k$?

Comment: So if $gcd(k,n) \not = 1$, then the order of $a^n$ will not be $k$ since $a^n$'s order will approach $1$ faster. But if $gcd(k,n) = 1$, then we know that $a^n$ has to have order $k$. Would this imply that there are $\varphi(k)$ numbers in $1, a, a^2, \ldots,a^{k-1}$ that have order $k$? Or is my thought process off?

Comment: @user1359900: Your answer is exactly right! You'll probably want to put in a few more details about your argument if this is a homework assignment :)

Comment: @Zev - Correct me if I'm wrong here. Let $gcd(k,n) = d$. If the order of $a$ is $k$, then $a^n$ has order $\frac{k}{d}$. Which works out since if $d=1$, then the order will still be $k$, but if $d\not=1$, then $\frac{k}{d}$ will be an integer $\lt k$.